# How to use transients values in Domain Class for Grails 2.4.4

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Folder Structure: 
HRMS

```
Domain 
    com.hrms.ei.employeeinfo
Controllers
    com.hrms.ei.employeeinformation.controller
Views
    employeeinformation 
        edit.gsp 
        list.gsp
        show.gsp
```

I have a column date_of_birth which is passed from gsp ---> Controller ---> Domain and used in employeeinfo.groovy(domain) for validation purpose. But I don't want to create column for date_of_birth in the employeeinfo table, so I used `static transients = ['date_of_birth']`. I declared that column as `Date date_of_birth` in the domain class.

While using `static transients = ['date_of_birth']` it returns null, but if I remove `static transients` from the domain class, the column is getting created in DB. The same logic is working in Grails 1.3.7.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add bindable for the property in constraints section.
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Constraints/bindable.html

Comment: Hi ... These are code given inside the Domain Class                              static constraints = {
date_of_birth bindable: false
}
static transients = ['date_of_birth']
Date date_of_birth     but it doesn't work .. still it returns null ...

Comment: If its date field then the parameter will be binded differently, you can check http://www.tothenew.com/blog/new-data-binding-features-in-grails-2-3/ and the g:datePicker code which render _year month fields for date binding
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/datePicker.html

Comment: Thank u dude... Its working right now ...i change the code as                     date_of_birth  bindable:true,nullable:false